# How to compute % return of a strategy with Vega notional

Tags: returns, vega, pnl

I'm currently running some backtest on a strategy 2 legs and where the product traded is straddle.

I aim on this strategy to be Vega neutral thanks to a balance between 2 legs.
Thus, I deal with Vega notional to refer to which size I want to trade.

I end up with a $Pnl that I'd like to turn into a Pnl in % to see what is my actual return over a week, a month, a year, etc...
To me I needed to see what is my notional, and how it evolves when the strategy is running (you take positions and delta hedge everyday), but I can't find something that make sense to me.

Thank you for your help already, and feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Not too sure it helps a lot but thank you for trying !

Answer (score 1):

Use the required margin as the notional. You'll have to look up the value based on the exchange.

Comment: I use a backtest without any margin so I don't really know how relavant is it for me....

Comment: When you purchase a stock, it is implicitly 100% margined, ie you put in the full price of the stock in cash, and that is the notional. The required margin is the notional for any returns you want to compute, no matter the scenario.

Comment: And for options ?

Comment: Depends on the exchange, which is what I mean you need to look it up. For retail equity options, IIRC it's fully margined (100%) for long, but something quite different for short.